# Redirect insecure requests of one tomcat application to secure port and don't redirect requests of another application

Tags: tomcat, redirect

I have two web applications running under tomcat 7.0

1. https:// secure.example.com:8443
2. http:// insecure.example.com:8080

They have two separate "host" records in server.xml (different domains, separate locations).

**I need first one to be available via HTTPS only. In other words I need insecure requests to secure application to be redirected to secure port. But insecure application still must be available via HTTP.**

- http:// insecure.example.com:8080 - OK
- https:// secure.example.com:8443 - OK
- http:// secure.example.com:8080 --> https:// secure.example.com:8443

I know it is possible to specify "redirectPort" in insecure Connector (server.xml) but then HTTP requests to any of the applications(domains) will be redirected to secure port.

Is it possible to configure that with single tomcat instance?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by setting separate "Service" element in conf/server.xml.

For example you have

```
<Service name="Catalina">
  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" />
  <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="insecure.example.com">
      <Host name="insecure.example.com"  appBase="insecure" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
```

Now add additional service section

```
<Service name="SecureApps">
  <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
            keystoreFile="/usr/local/tomcat/keys/keystore.p12" keystorePass="mySecret" keystoreType="pkcs12"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
  <Engine name="SecureEngine" defaultHost="secure.example.com">
      <Host name="secure.example.com"  appBase="secure" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
```

Thus secure application won't be available via insecure connections, as HTTP port is served by another service.

With regards to HTTP(8080)->HTTPS(8443) redirecting, probably there is better way in such configuration, but it is possible to setup second "Host" section with name="secure.example.com" inside "Catalina" service, and deploy some web application containing simple servlet redirecting any requests come to it to specified secure url.

For example

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Redirect to secure port</display-name>
    <description>
        This is a simple web application which redirects you to secure port
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RedirectServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mycompany.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RedirectServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

RedirectServlet.java

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RedirectServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException
    {
        String url = "https://secure.example.com:8443/";

        response.sendRedirect(url);

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException
    {
        String url = "https://secure.example.com:8443/";

        response.sendRedirect(url);

    }
}
```